# remove div where attr value does not contain string

Tags: jquery

I have this dynamically formed divs that appear inside an already existing div.

```
<div id="onlineList">
   <div  id="ajaxChat_u_109" name="username1" data-gender="8">whatever1</div>
   <div  id="ajaxChat_u_109" name="username2" data-gender="8">whatever2</div>
   <div  id="ajaxChat_u_109" name="username3" data-gender="8">whatever3</div>
   <div  id="ajaxChat_u_109" name="username4" data-gender="8">whatever4</div>
   <div  id="ajaxChat_u_109" name="username5" data-gender="8">whatever5</div>
   <div  id="ajaxChat_u_109" name="username6" data-gender="8">whatever6</div>
   <div  id="ajaxChat_u_109" name="username7" data-gender="8">whatever7</div>
</div>
```

What i want to make is a jquery function that removes the divs that do not contain the string passed by an inputfield.

```
    <input type="text" id="searchuser" value="" />
    <input type="button" id="gosearchuser" value=">" />
```

I've put together a Jfidle http://jsfiddle.net/38Ndw/1/ where you can see jquery that's obviously not working.

Comment: The string (from `searchuser`?) should match the *text* of the `div`? Or the `name` attribute? Or the `data-gender`?

Comment: your html is  not valid .id should be  unique

Comment: It should match the name attributes value. To be more precise, if the string is contained in the name it should stay and otherwize removed.

Comment: @ Manishankar  if i where trying to select on that id i would have a problem indeed. ;-) By making this example more generic i accidentally pasted the same id's. It should not interfere however in this matter.

Comment: +1 just for confusing so many programmers :) *(I thought it was pretty clear, but waited for ages for anyone to get it exactly right, even after hints)*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This answer assumes a *case-insensitive*, *partial match* search of the `name` attributes is required (now confirmed from comments):

For your specific example problem, I kind of like `slideUp()` and `slideDown()` as they move the remaining elements correctly and leave them in place so the filter can be changed again and again:

### Final JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/38Ndw/25/

It uses a `filter` function which is basically a callback that gets passed each matching element in turn. If the function returns true (to include) or false (to exclude) this changes the resulting list. `slideUp()` (was `remove()`) is then applied only to the resulting matches.

This one also includes the case-insensitive matching you wanted.

```
$("#gosearchuser").on("click", function (event) {
    var searchuser = $('#searchuser').val().toLowerCase();
    $('#onlineList').children('div').slideDown().filter(function(){
        return $(this).attr('name').toLowerCase().indexOf(searchuser) == -1;
    }).slideUp();
});
```

This is also slightly more efficient as it only searches for `$('#searchuser')` once (which is preferable to searching the same element/value, *over and over*, for every matching element).

---

Old versions below

### JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/38Ndw/8/

It uses a *filter function* which is bascially a callback that gets passed each matching element in turn. If it returns true (to include) or false (to exclude) this changes the resulting list. `remove()` is then applied only to the result matches.

```
$("#gosearchuser").on("click", function (event) {
    $('#onlineList').children('div').filter(function(){
        return $(this).attr('name').indexOf($('#searchuser').val()) == -1;
    }).remove();
});
```

Ideally the filter should be specific enough to not catch any other elements. In this case it matches just the child `div`s of `#onlineList` but it could just as easily be:

all children of the list (fastest):

```
$('#onlineList').children().filter...
```

or match just those with a `name=` attribute:

```
$('#onlineList').children('[name]').filter...
```

or just `div`s with a `name=` attribute:

```
$('#onlineList').children('div[name]').filter...
```

which can also be combined with the parent id selector:

```
$('#onlineList > div').filter...
$('#onlineList > div[name]').filter...
```

*based on your comments the duplicate ids are just in the sample data, so I have not addressed those*

Mr7-itsurdeveloper (below) made an interesting suggestion, that you simply hide the element rather that remove them. You can then repeat the button over and over. Instead of classes I have used `hide()` and `show()`:

### JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/38Ndw/17/

```
$("#gosearchuser").on("click", function (event) {
    $('#onlineList').children('div').show().filter(function(){
        return $(this).attr('name').indexOf($('#searchuser').val()) == -1;
    }).hide();
});
```

### personally I like `fadeIn()` and `fadeOut()` best

### JsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/38Ndw/18/

```
$("#gosearchuser").on("click", function (event) {
    $('#onlineList').children('div').fadeIn().filter(function(){
        return $(this).attr('name').indexOf($('#searchuser').val()) == -1;
    }).fadeOut();
});
```

### Update: Case-insensitive matching

You normally just need to call `toLowerCase` on both strings before comparing the strings:

### JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/38Ndw/24/

```
$("#gosearchuser").on("click", function (event) {
    var searchuser = $('#searchuser').val().toLowerCase();
    $('#onlineList').children('div').filter(function(){
        return $(this).attr('name').toLowerCase().indexOf(searchuser) == -1;
    }).remove();
});
```

Comment: Is it a simple thing to make the stringsearch case insensitive?

Comment: $("#gosearchuser").on("click", function (event) {
    $('#onlineList').children('div').fadeIn().filter(function(){
        return $(this).attr('name').toLowerCase().indexOf($('#searchuser').val().toLowerCase()) == -1;
    }).fadeOut();
});
});

Comment: Updated to match requirements :) Also added a slide version (which better suits your selection method).

Answer (score 4):

Try with this using `.filter()`:

```
$("#gosearchuser").on("click", function (event) {
    $('#onlineList').children('div').filter(function(){
        return $(this).attr('name').indexOf($('#searchuser').val()) !== -1;
    }).remove();
});
```

#### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/38Ndw/15/)

---

### Note:

You have a invalid html markup because of duplicacy of ids again and again.

Comment: Why use `find('> div')` instead of the more readable `children('div')`?

Comment: I just make sure to get the attribute of children, with use of `.find()` although `.children()` yes your suggestion is also good.

Comment: Actually I have to take away my upvote: the question states **"contain the string"** (not exact match)

Comment: @TruBlueAussie yeah again you are correct, actually OP has not responded in any of the answer posts i think, and i just updated OP's fiddle where he/she is checking the name attribute to remove.

Comment: Half the job here is working out the actual question, but the title states "does not contain string" :) The intended purpose looks like a really lame auto-complete so exact match would be really really bad :) We will see what the OP says.

Comment: OP just confirmed below he wants substring matching. Please update so I can upvote (`filter` was good choice) :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$("#gosearchuser").on("click", function (event) {
    var inputVal = $('#searchuser').val();
    $('#onlineList').children().each(function(){
      if($(this).attr('name').indexOf(inputVal)==-1)
         (this).remove();

    });
});
```

### [Working JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/38Ndw/11/)

Comment: This searches the text within the div and not the name attribute. ;-)

Comment: Question was little confusing coz of this line "..divs that do not contain the string passed". Updated answer now.

Comment: Going by the answers this is the most confusing question I have seen lately :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$("#gosearchuser").on("click", function (event) {
    $('#onlineList').children('div').filter(function(){
        return $(this).attr('name').toLowerCase().indexOf($('#searchuser').val().toLowerCase()) == -1;
    }).remove();
});
```

[Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/38Ndw/14/)

Comment: You have the logic reversed :( See question: *"removes the divs that do not contain the string"*. Yours removes that divs that *do* contain the string.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to check for attribute `name` of div then you have to do like this:

```
    $("#gosearchuser").on("click", function (event) {

    var  $searchparam = $('#searchuser').val();

    $('div#onlineList div').each(function () {

        if ($(this).attr('name') == $searchparam ){

        } 
        else {

            this.remove();

        }
      });

 });
```

[**UPDATED FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/ehsansajjad465/nLz7X/1/)

If you are trying to check for text of div then you have to do like this:

```
    $("#gosearchuser").on("click", function (event) {

       var  $searchparam = $('#searchuser').val();

    $('div#onlineList div').each(function () {

        if ($(this).text().trim() === $searchparam ){


        } else {

            this.remove();

        }
     });

 });
```

[**FIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/ehsansajjad465/5pa3P/3/)

Comment: Read the question: "that removes the divs that **do not** contain the string"

Comment: There is a really nice button called `TidyUp` in JSFiddle... Get to know and love your `Tidyup` button. You can probably guess what it does :)

Comment: -1: I tried hinting, but it is still wrong after 5 edits. The question states **"contains the string"** not *exact match* :(

Comment: This sure looks like it. :-) What i want now is that the all the names that contain the searchstring should stay and otherwise removed.

Comment: currently its happening what you are saying, you want complete string match?

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie OP is saying this is what he/she wants

Comment: No. They said: "It should match the name attributes value. To be more precise, if the string *is contained in the name* it should stay and otherwize removed."

Comment: i need to replace ``===`` with ``indexOf()``

Answer (score 0):

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/surendraVsingh/38Ndw/6/)**

**Jquery**

```
$("#gosearchuser").on("click", function (event) {
    var $searchparam = $('#searchuser').val();
        $('div[name="' + $searchparam + '"]').hide();
});
```

Comment: What's with all the `5`'s in the code? Keyboard broken? :)

Comment: PS. The OP has confirmed *an exact match is not required*. Partial match is needed.

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie Ha ha ha..seems to be. Updated the code

Answer (score 0):

use following code ,this will work

```
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>




   <script>
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#gosearchuser").on("click", function (event) {

  peoplediv   = $('#onlineList').children('div');
  searchparam = $('#searchuser').val();

    $(peoplediv).each(function () {  

        if ($(this).attr('name') == searchparam ){

            alert('jaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa');     
            $(peoplediv).not(this).remove();  



        } 
        else { 
            return;

        } 
 });

    });    }); 



</script>
```

Comment: This one is still wrong (partial matching is required), but hiding, instead of removing, the elements is something not covered elsewhere.

Comment: I meant the hiding was a good suggestion :) Your code is still incorrect for the requirements :(

Answer (score 0):

Ok,

With many thanks to you all i've chosen TrueBlueAussie to have provided the answer i needed.

This is the code now that also makes the search caseinsensitive,

```
$("#gosearchuser").on("click", function (event) {
$('#onlineList').children('div').fadeIn().filter(function(){
    return $(this).attr('name').toLowerCase().indexOf($('#searchuser').val().toLowerCase()) == -1;
}).fadeOut();
```

});
});

Comment: Sorry about that. I'm new here and wasn't aware of the accept-answer button.

Comment: That's OK. You're new here :) Thanks for the accept. You should probably delete this answer now (to avoid down-votes)